# How to show that $1 + p$ has order $p^{n-1}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ for $p$ an odd prime?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

$(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is the group of invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$.

To find the order of $1+p$, we start by expanding $(1 + p)^{p}$ using the binomial theorem:

$(1 + p)^p = 1 + p \cdot p + {p \choose 2}\cdot p^2 + \dots \equiv 1 + p^2 \pmod {p^3}$. Similarly,

$(1 + p)^{p^2} \equiv 1 + p^3 \pmod {p^4}$

$\cdots$

$(1 + p)^{p^{n-1}} \equiv 1 + p^{n} \pmod{p^{n+1}}$.

I'm thrown off by $\pmod{p^{n+1}}$. I need $p^{n}$ where there is $p^{n+1}$.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: Oh, so because $p^{n+1} \mid (1 + p)^{p^{n-1}} - 1 - p^n$, this implies $p^n$ divides the same also.

Comment: Well, if the congruence was modulo $p^n$, then your (correct) statement would become one saying that the power of $1+p$ was merely congruent to $1$, which is not good enough for your purpose.

Comment: @Lubin can you explain some more, I don't fully understand your comment.

Comment: You need a statement that says that when you calculate $(1+p^mu)^p$ for a number $u$ prime to $p$, you get something of form $1+p^{m+1}u'$ for another number $u'$ also prime to $p$. If you’ll look at your two illustrations (first two displays), you’ll see that what you objected to is exactly in the same form, first for $n=2$, then for $n=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept those identities, then $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}} \equiv 1+p^n \pmod{p^{n+1}}$ implies $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^n}$, so the order divides $p^{n-1}$, so the order is a power of $p$, but the lower powers of $p$ cannot give $1$ by the lower identities.